# DNA strand displacement and Branch migration- the same or different or interrelated?

Tags: dna, recombination

So, recently I have begun studying DNA strand displacement and then I come across the term 'branch migration' (p.s. I am not a biology major student). What I understand is that branch migration is part of the strand displacement process.

Or is it not? If branch migration is not a part of strand displacement, then what is it?
First, does strand displacement refer to the case where a single-strand 
(floating freely) is competing with the incumbent strand to pair with the complementary pair, resulting in the displacement of the incumbent strand? 
That means we have one DNA complex and one single-strand in the input and output. And second, does branch migration refers to the case where two DNA complexes exchange strands, resulting in two DNA complexes both in the input and output?

To me, both processes are involved in the displacement of strands (but I can't seem to find their differences).

Can someone kindly explain to me their difference, if there are any?

Comment: Branch migration is a part of the DNA strand displacement process. http://slideplayer.com/slide/12266786/72/images/46/12.+20+The+Holliday+model+of+homologous+recombination.jpg

Comment: @MartinKlvana So this confirms to my second statement on branch migration. Will this apply to the first statement as well?